# Jquery-Using the 'show' and 'hide' on click function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, if-statement

I have an animated navigation (http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/03/16/expanding-image-menu/) and have modified it so I have a fader off to the left side. All I want it to do is 'hide' when the menu is in its expanded state, and 'show' when the menu is collapsed. Here is the code I have written thus far:

```
$menuItemsImgWrapper.on('click', function () {
    if ($('.ei_descr').is(':visible')) {
        $('#fader').hide();
    } else {
        $('#fader').show();
    }
});
```

The fader hides fine, but will not show. If anyone can give me a clue as to why this is, I'd really appreciate it. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Can you post the corresponding html also? Or a working demo/fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check what the plugin does to handle opening/closing the text:

```
$menuItemsImgWrapper.bind('click.ExpandingMenu', function(e) {
    var $this   = $(this).parent(),
    idx     = $this.index();

    if(current === idx) {
        slideOutItem($menuItems.eq(current), false, 1500, 'easeOutQuint', true);
        current = -1;
    }
    else{
        if(validCurrent() && current !== idx)
                slideOutItem($menuItems.eq(current), false, 250, 'jswing');

        current = idx;
            slideOutItem($this, true, 250, 'jswing');
    }
    return false;
});
```

why don't you use that event and that if/else to hide #fader?

something like

```
$menuItemsImgWrapper.bind('click.ExpandingMenu', function(e) {
    var $this   = $(this).parent(),
    idx     = $this.index();

    if(current === idx) {
        //then it collapses the text
        $('#fader').hide();
    }
    else{
        //then it expands the text
        $('#fader').show();
    }
    return false;
});
```

Comment: That works awesome! Thanks, can't believe I didn't think of that! You're a lifesaver!

Comment: This is the first time I've used this site...so since I can't vote it up, I just check the checkmark. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

This is because the element with the class: ".ei_descr" is still visible. You have only stated to hide an element with the id: "#fader".

Hence, the code in the if statement will always evaluate to true unless you also hide ".ei_descr".

Comment: Okay...I've modified the code but am still having the same problem. I'm new to the jquery seen and am still trying to grasp how it all works. Thanks for the response, I will keep trying different variations.

$menuItemsImgWrapper.on('click', function(){
if ($('.ei_descr').is(':visible')) {
$('.ei_descr').show();
$('#fader').hide();
      
} else {
$('.ei_descr').hide();
$('#fader').show();
}      
});

Comment: looks like you are still not hiding it though. Should be: if ($('.ei_descr').is(':visible')) { $('.ei_descr').hide();

Answer (score 0):

:visible checks for opacity and visibility.
fade() though turns the object into display: none;. So your object is visible but not shown on display.

Answer (score 0):

Just use Jquery's toggle method:

```
$menuItemsImgWrapper.on('click', function () {
    $('#fader').toggle();
});
```

it will hide #fader if it is visible and show it if hidden

Comment: Due to the nature of navigation bar in place, using the toggle function isn't an option. The fader div is placed to the left of the navigation menu. The navigation menu expands and covers the fader div and if the click function is triggered every time the 'menuItemsWrapper' is clicked, it ends up showing over the navigation menu.

Comment: added another answer using the code that the plugin uses to detect opening/closing